# Binding a right context in ES6 class when using Q.nfcall

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, q

I'm using `Q` package for an async call:

```
let loadPromise = Q.nfcall(m.loadObj,data);
```

`m` is an instance of this class:

```
class Base {

    constructor() {
        this._name = null;;
    }

    loadObj(data) {
        this._name = data;              
    }
}
```

The issue is that `this` is `undefined` after entering `loadObj` method.

As mentioned in `Q` wiki:

> If you are working with methods, instead of simple functions, you can
>   easily run in to the usual problems where passing a method to another
>   function—like Q.nfcall—"un-binds" the method from its owner. To avoid
>   this, you can either use Function.prototype.bind

How can I bind the right context to `loadObj` method ?

Comment: `let loadPromise = Q.nfcall(m.loadObj.bind(m), data);`

Comment: `loadObj` is not a [node-style callback function](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#interfacing-with-nodejs-callbacks) at all, it's not even asynchronous! You cannot use `nfcall` here!

Comment: @Bergi you right. I've just read it in the docs: "If you're working with functions that make use of the Node.js callback pattern, where callbacks are in the form of function(err, result), Q provides a few useful..."

Answer (score 0):

As Q's doc states - you can use `ninvoke` to avoid un-binding like this:

```
let loadPromise = Q.ninvoke(m, 'loadObj', data);
```

Apparently, you can also do re-binding here:

```
let loadPromise = Q.nfcall(m.loadObj.bind(m), data);
```